como obtener de cualquier archivo en c los datos binarios en bruto de cada byte o el entero
Queria saber si se puede obtener en c desde cualquier tipo de archivo (sin importar si es binario o el tipo de archivo que sea), el codigo binario o entero de cada caracter o byte que se lea desde el archivo.
por ejemplo si en un archivo hay "3f!", poder obtener el equivalente binario o entero.
igual si el archivo está en binario, poder leer por ejemplo dos bytes y que quede en alguna variable el codigo binario o entero de esos byte.
Es decir si hay cualquier caracter raro en el archivo, obtener 00101011 o lo que sea o su valor en entero.
Desde ya muchas gracias, que se que no es algo muy comun y no se me ocurre como hacerlo, ni usando fread ni las funciones de archivo secuencial.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Sí, es posible. Los archivos no son otra cosa que una serie unos y ceros. Lo único que cambia es cómo se interpretan.
De hecho, los editores binarios como HxD hacen algo así. La interfaz se ve así:

Solo tienes que abrir el archivo con fopen:
FILE* archivo = fopen("archivo.txt", "rb");

Y leer sus bytes con fread o fgetc:
int byte = fgetc(archivo);

Puedes imprimir el número entero o el símbolo correspondiente a ese número.
printf("Caracter: %c Entero: %i", byte, byte);

Si quieres ver el número binario, puedes calcularlo a partir del número entero. En internet hay ejemplos si necesitas guiarte.

Justo lo que buscaba, mil gracias por tu amabilidad de responder.

Muy agradecido, saludos.
